# PHP month array original value

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm trying to submit an array of dates through a form. I've figured out how to make the number range display as a month but then it's in the wrong format for the form submission.

Working:

```
$Startmonth=date('n');
$monthArray = range(1,12);
?>

<select class="bkwidgetdd" name="CIM" size="1">
    <!-- CIM = CheckInMonth -->
    <?php
    foreach ($monthArray as $month) {
        $selected = ($month == $Startmonth) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Not Working:

```
$Startmonth=date('n');
$monthArray = array(1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb', 3 => 'Mar', 4 => 'Apr', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'Jun', 7 => 'Jul', 8 => 'Aug', 9 => 'Sep', 10 => 'Oct', 11 => 'Nov', 12 => 'Dec');
?>

<select class="bkwidgetdd" name="CIM" size="1">
    <!-- CIM = CheckInMonth -->
    <?php
    foreach ($monthArray as $month) {
        $selected = ($month == $Startmonth) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I know that it's breaking because it's submitting the months as the string instead of the number value. How do I have it display as months but submit as number?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, need the array's key to use as the values:

```
foreach ($monthArray as $key => $month) {
    $selected = ($key == $Startmonth) ? 'selected' : '';
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$month.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: need to check with key $key == $Startmonth  ,

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
    $Startmonth=date('n');
    $monthArray = array(1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb', 3 => 'Mar', 4 => 'Apr', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'Jun', 7 => 'Jul', 8 => 'Aug', 9 => 'Sep', 10 => 'Oct', 11 => 'Nov', 12 => 'Dec');
?>

<select class="bkwidgetdd" name="CIM" size="1">
     <!-- CIM = CheckInMonth -->
     <?php
          foreach ($monthArray as $key => $month){
              $selected = ($key == $Startmonth) ? 'selected' : '';
              echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$month.'</option>';
          }
     ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Suresh, flagged the other because it came in first. Appreciate it though!